# Can I use wildcard for mimetype in google-picker View?

Tags: javascript, google-picker

I want to create google picker view where user can select all files which mimetype starts with "video/*".  I know that google picker has specific view type ViewId.DOCS_VIDEOS, but for some reason it doesn't load all videos.

For example videos with mimetype "video/vnd.dlna.mpeg-tts".

When I try to use View.setMimeTypes("video/*") it loads nothing.

Comment: Try using [`google.picker.​DocsView`](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/reference.html#DocsView) and set the type to [`Type.VIDEO`](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/reference#Type) which will check if the item is a video. Check if this will return different number of videos than using **`ViewId.DOCS_VIDEOS`**. Hope this helps.

Comment: As far as I understood from documentation and the Type.VIDEO is to check the returned document type. And not something I can pass to DocsView. DocsView requires ViewId argument which can be VIewId.DOCS_VIDEO or DOCS_IMAGES_AND_VIDEOS for me, but both of them doesn't show the video with mimetype "video/vnd.dlna.mpeg-tts"

Comment: I'm not sure if you can set wildcard for the mimetype. But as stated in the [forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-picker-api/fvJIWTKAeK0), you can try to list a bunch of comma-delimited mimetypes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for trying to help! I'm doing that for music and specifying bunch of comma separated mimetypes. But didn't wanted to put me under maintenance of video mimetypes, but seems it is the only way i can take ...